# I uploaded data to R from excel and when I check if a column exists, it returns FALSE. How do I correct this so that R can read or recognize the data?

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I am trying to separate a column.. I have columns (date, lmp, node). The code recognizes date but does not recognize `lmp` and `node`.

```
names(Pjm) 
# [1] "date" "lmp"  "node"

names(Pjm) <- c("date", "lmp", "node")

str(Pjm)
#tibble [210,240 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ date: POSIXct[1:210240], format: "2021-01-01 00:00:00" "2021-01-01 01:00:00" "2021-01-01 02:00:00" "2021-01-01 03:00:00" ...
# $ lmp : num [1:210240] 19.2 17.8 17.8 17.8 17.9 ...
# $ node: chr [1:210240] "AEP_GEN" "AEP_GEN" "AEP_GEN" "AEP_GEN" ...

exists("lmp")
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: What does `"lmp" %in% names(Pjm)` return, true of false? Also, when you say "separate a column", could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: `exists("lmp")` will check whether there is an object named `"lmp"`in your global environment. However, `"lmp"` is a column of your dataset `Pjm`. Hence you will get FALSE Try with `exists("lmp", where = Pjm)` instead. In contrast `exists("date")` will return TRUE as `date()` is a base R function.

Comment: exist ("lmp", where = pjm) returns TRUE.  I wish to separate or reshape my data from a single column to rows (node) to several e.g  Date  lmp node                                                                                     .                                                          2:00   10    AEP                                                                        '                                                          3:00    12    DY                                                          '                                                           4:00    12    OH

Comment: `lmp <- Pjm$lmp` would make a vector object called `lmp` that is a copy of the `lmp` column of `Pjm`.